# This expression was expected to have type IWebProxy but here has type WebProxy

Tags: types, f#

I'm playing around with a simple example of f# from [this nice tutorial](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/installing-and-using/). And ran into this very strange error. After adding a proxy to webrequest, It tells me that type WebProxy is not compatible with expected type IWebProxy. This is kind of strange, why my C# hammer no work in F#?

What am I doing wrong here?

```
let downloadUrlToFile url file =
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri(url))
    req.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 444)
    use res = req.GetResponse()
    use stream = res.GetResponseStream()
    use reader = new IO.StreamReader(stream)
    let timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyy-MM-dd")
    let path = sprintf "%s.%s.html" file timestamp
    use writer = new IO.StreamWriter(path)
    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd())
    printfn "done loading %s to %s" url file
```

The error message

```
This expression was expected to have type
    IWebProxy    
but here has type
    WebProxy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others already explained, the problem is that `=` is the comparison operator. In this case, you need an assignment, which is `<-`.

However, F# actually performs upcasts implicitly in a couple of cases and assignment is one of them, so you do not need to add  `:> IWebProxy` to cast the object. The following will work just fine:

```
req.Proxy <- new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 444)
```

Aside from assignment, F# also does implicit upcasting when passing arguments to methods or functions. It does not do this for the comparison operator (because you want to know, without any ambiguities, what types are compared.)

Comment: Thanks for the teaching moment Tomas - F# newb here 5 years later!

Comment: @NormanH Thanks to StackOverflow that 5 year old posts are still archived here! Happy this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are at least two things, that you do not expect here:

- `req.Proxy = new WebProxy(...)` is a comparison, you probably want `req.Proxy <- new WebProxy(...)` instead.
- F# does not do automatic upcasting. As such, you might need to do the static upcast with something like `req.Proxy <- new WebProxy(...) :> _`. This tells F# to "upcast to whatever fits here".

(I did not actually run your code, so you might have more issues, but those two are certainly important for a C# programmer.)

Answer (score 1):

F# doesn't automatically upcast values like C# does, so you need to explicitly cast the `WebProxy` object to `IWebProxy`, like so:

```
req.Proxy <- WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 444) :> IWebProxy
```

Also important: the assignment syntax in F# is `<-`, not `=` as in C#. If you use `=`, you'll get an error message like this:

```
Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    bool    
is not compatible with type
    IWebProxy    
The type 'bool' is not compatible with the type 'IWebProxy'
```